# Problems with setting the color for div's with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jquery/java script and trying for find out how it works. I'm trying to recreate this page http://jenniferdewalt.com/mondrian.html.

My html is the following

`<DOCTYPE html>`
`<html>`
    `head`
    `<title>Change the color</title>`
        `<meta http-equiv = 'content-type' content = 'text/html';charset='windows-1251'>`
        `<link rel='stylesheet' href='index.css'>`
        `<script type = 'text/javascript' src = 'jquery-2.1.0.min.js'></script>`

```
`</head>`

`<body>`
    `<div class='b-body_text'>
            <div class='b-text'>
                Pick a color and paint the canvas
            </div>
    </div>`

    `<div class='b-container'>
        <div class='b-container__squares'>
            <ul class='b-squares'>`
                `<li class='b-squares__item' id='b-item__red'></li>`
                `<li class='b-squares__item' id='b-item__yellow'></li>`
                `<li class='b-squares__item' id='b-item__blue'></li>`
                `<li class='b-squares__item' id='b-item__white'></li>`
            `</ul>`
        `</div>`

        `<div class='b-container__table'>`
            `<div class='b-table'>`
                `<div class='b-row1'>`
                    `<div class='b-row' id='row1_box1'></div>`
                    `<div class='b-row' id='row1_box2'></div>`
                    `<div class='b-row' id='row1_box3'></div>`
                    `<div class='b-row' id='row1_box4'></div>`
                `</div>`
                ********** 4 rows***************
        `</div>`
        `</div>`
        `</body>`
         `</html>`
```

I need to pick the square and color the canvas with the color of this square. Tried to do smth. like that

```
`$(document).ready(function()`
```

`{somefunction1 = function()`
    `{
        $('.b-squares__item').click(receiveColor);
    }`

```
`receiveColor = function()
{
    var color  = $(this).css('background-color');
}`

`$('.b-row').click(setColor);`

`setColor = function()
{
    $(this).css('background', somefunction1);
}`
```

`})`

but it doesn't work.

Then I looked at the js file from the site, tried to recreate it and it still has some problems

```
`$(document).ready(function () {`

`var color = 'white'`

`$('.b-squares__item').on('click', function () {
    color = $(this).css('background-color');
})`

`$('.b-row').on('click', function () {

    $(this).css('background-color', color );
})`;
```

`});`

I cannot understand where'white' in var color = 'white' is taken from, so maybe that's where the problem is from?

Answer (score 2):

Why go through all these process, why not just do something like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    $('.b-squares__item').click(function () {
          $(this).css('background-color', 'white');

     });
      });
```

Or use **addClass** to avoid inline CSS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
        $('.b-squares__item').click(function () {
              $(this).addClass('class-name');

         });
          });
```

**CSS of the class you're adding**

```
.class-name {
   background-color: white;
}
```

**Method for your case:** In your case and from your comment, see the example below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".b-squares__item").click(function () {
        $(".b-row").eq($(this).index()).toggleClass($(".b-squares__item").attr("class"));
    });

});
```

[See working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/70bd1pqw/1/)

Comment: actually, I want my canvas divs ('.b-row') to change the color from white to the color of the chosen square ('b-squares__item'). So, this won't work